# How to declare a global numpy.ndarray in cython?

Tags: python, numpy, global-variables, cython

I want to create a signal processing algorithm that needs to hold some internal state in a numpy array.

For speed, I coded that in cython and declared the state a global variable like this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy  as np
cdef np.ndarray delay_buffer
```

However, what I really would like to do is this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
DTYPE = np.float32
ctypedef np.float32_t DTYPE_t
cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t] delay_buffer
```

This I can do anyhwere else, but not in the global scope. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to accomplish this?

No. As the error says, `Buffer types only allowed as function local variables`.

One alternative is to use a monolithic `main` function. This really only takes indenting everything but it means that you can only share so much.

My favourite alternative would be to upgrade to the modern method of using memoryviews:

```
cdef DTYPE_t[:] delay_buffer
```

The should be faster, cleaner and no less powerful.

Comment: Well, memoryviews does not have ndarray methods such as shape(), max() etc.

Comment: *Typically* it's best to use Python functions on untyped data for lower overheads. You would then have something like `delay_buffer = delay_array = ...` where `delay_array` is untyped. But I'd also often recommend unrolling loops like `max` into inline Cython functions as the overhead is often way lower. // Also memoryviews *do* have a `shape` attribute. // Finally, outside of bottleneck scenarios, you can run `np.max(memoryview)` which makes a noncopying Numpy array so has high constant overhead but looks almost as pretty.

Comment: Thank you so much Veedrac! I am sorry that I posted my point due to my ignorance - I wasn't aware that memoryviews also have a shape attribute. And also, credit to @JoshAdel, memoryviews can be coerced to np.ndarray too. http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy